# Facebook App Center on Desktop Game

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, desktop, facebook-unity-sdk

I've been developing a desktop PC game in Unity which connects to Facebook in order to post messages about the player's progress (high score etc). The chosen method of how the app integrates with Facebook is currently set to "Website with Facebook Login". Everything is already set up and working (Open Graph stories, action and types) but after trying to submit the app for review, it appears desktop apps are not allowed to be configured this way.

The question I am asking is, if desktop apps are not allowed to use App Center, what are the preferred methods of posting messages to a users wall? There is the option of using normal feed posting but it is my understanding that this approach does not allow custom stories and will only display a generic message.

Does anyone have experience with the matter or perhaps has integrated it in their own game / app in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up a misconception in the question, an app can appear in Facebook's App Center even if it doesn't publish anything to Facebook - it must be on a supported platform (iOS, Android, or Facebook Canvas), though. And an app that doesn't appear in App Center can still publish to the site, too. The two are not connected.

That said: The feed dialog is actually highly customizable, and relatively easy to integrate into any game that can invoke a Web browser. Check out its [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for details.

Additionally, you can create highly structured messages using the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). Doing this requires you to get the user's [authorization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/), probably using a Web dialog. You need to request the publish_actions permission to do so; a few games (case study [here](https://developers.facebook.com/showcase/avengers/), e.g.) have had remarkable success building out appealing OG implementations.

None of this is really specific to the Unity SDK at this point, I'm afraid, as it doesn't currently have native desktop support (just iOS, Android, and web player). But I hope it's helpful.